# On the Fourier-Laplace transform of compactly supported distributions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions

Let $\mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of all compactly supported distributions on $\mathbb{R}$.

For $f\in \mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R})$, let $\widehat{f}$ denote the entire  extension of the Fourier transform of $f$.

**Question:** If $f_n\stackrel{n\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow}f$ in $\mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R})$, then does $\widehat{f}_n$ converge to  $\widehat{f}$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: Initial thoughts: Pointwise convergence is for free.  By the mean value property, it's sufficient to get $L^1$ convergence on compact subsets, so we might try to show there's a dominating function, or uniform integrability.  And if I'm not mistaken, $\mathcal{E}(\mathbb{R})$ is a Frechet space, so we have the uniform boundedness principle available, which seems like it ought to help.

Comment: @NateEldredge How is "X-wise convergence is for free" defined? If one knows (x) that elements in a bounded set in $\mathscr E'(\mathbb R)$ have "uniformly bounded" supports and orders, then the assertion follows trivially from formula (2) $\ |f(z)|\le\gamma\,(1+|z|)^N{\rm e}^{\,r|\rm{Im}\,z|} $ in the statement of the Paley−Wiener theorem in Rudin's *Functional Analysis* (Th. 7.23, p. 183 in my edition). Is (x) "for free"?

Comment: @TaQ: All I meant by "pointwise convergence is for free" was the trivial observation that we have $\widehat{f_n}(x) \to \widehat{f}(x)$ for each $x$, simply because $\widehat{f_n}(x) = \langle f_n, e^{i x \cdot}\rangle$.  I did not think as far ahead as you got.  It'd be great if you would post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me expand Nate Eldredge's comments. A more elementary proof than the one provided by Jochen Wengenroth, still requiring no computations, is as follows:

$\mathcal{E}'$ is the dual space of $C^\infty$, which is endowed with the Fréchet space topology given e.g. by the seminorms $\|f\|_k:=\|f\|_{C^k(B_k(0))}$. The fact that $f_n\to f$ in $\mathcal{E}'$ means that $\langle f_n,\phi\rangle\to\langle f,\phi\rangle$ for any $\phi\in C^\infty$.

Now the uniform boundedness principle holds also for linear maps from a Fréchet space to (say) a normed vector space. The proof is the same as that for the Banach space version; for details, see Theorem 2.6 in Rudin's Functional Analysis (2nd edition). Hence the $f_n$'s are equicontinuous, i.e. there exists $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $C>0$ such that
$$ |\langle f_n,\phi\rangle|\le C\|\phi\|_{C^k(B_k(0))}. $$
This gives $|\widehat{f_n}(\xi)|\le C\|e^{-2\pi i\langle\xi,\cdot\rangle}\|_{C^k(B_k(0))}\le C'(1+|\xi|^k)e^{2\pi k|\xi|}$ for $\xi\in\mathbb{C}$. Also, $\widehat{f_n}(\xi)\to\widehat{f}(\xi)$ for every $\xi\in\mathbb{C}$ (since it corresponds to evaluation of $f_n$ on the test function $e^{-2\pi i\langle\xi,\cdot\rangle}$). So you have a locally equibounded sequence of pointwise converging holomorphic functions and this implies your claim. This clearly works in any dimension.

Comment: It seems your argument proves something stronger because you are using the weak-$\ast$ topology on $\mathcal{E}'$ instead of the strong topology as in Jochen's answer. Although, I don't remember if the two topologies are equivalent from the point of view of convergence of sequence because of more Bairology.

Comment: They are equivalent for convergence of sequences because of *compactology* ($\mathcal E'$ is a Montel space, i.e., the closed bounded sets are compact, and weakly convergent sequences are bounded).

Answer (score 5):

Besides the direct approach to such continuity questions as in Nate Eldredge's comment one can try to use a closed graph argument. The closed graph theorem holds for *ultrabornological* domain spaces (like the space $\mathcal E'(\mathbb R)$ of compactly supported distributions endowed with the topology of uniform convergence on bounded subsets of $\mathcal E(\mathbb R)$) and *webbed* range spaces -- a very large class of locally convex spaces containing all Frechet spaces and thus, in particular, the space of entire functions. By Nate's remark that *pointwise convergence is for free* the Fourier transform $f\mapsto \hat f$ has closed graph and is thus continuous.

Of course, this is locally convex overkill -- but avoids concrete calculations.